# Complex custom button responsibility

Tags: android

I have created custom button that have two states: `create_state` and `login_state`.
In `create_state`, if pressed, it should switch to another activity where user can fill profile creation form, then go back to main activity, and switch to state `login_state`, so pressing button logon user.

I have done that in my ProfileButton class. And now I see that there are some problems.
For example when I use:

```
Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(this.getContext(), NewProfileActivity.class);
Activity a = (Activity)this.getContext();
int requestCode = 0;
a.startActivityForResult(goToNextActivity, requestCode);
```

my `void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {..}` declared in ProfileButton class does not start after second activity `finish()`.

So better way is to manage this in parent Activity of that button?
All click handlers should be in Activity?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I guess you have to manually set the result that you need to return before finishing the activity.

use `setResult()` method in `NewProfileActivity` just before `finish()` method is called

Comment: I do so. Problem is different. onActivityResult is in ProfileButton, not in Activity.

Comment: Not sure how we can possibly have onActivityResult()  not in a class that extends Activity